# expected '}' at end of input

Tags: c++, c

No matter what I try I keep getting these five errors. I just can't see what could be wrong. Also any idea why the same error appears three times?

62: error: expected ')' before ';' token

62: error: expected ';' before ')' token

84: error: expected '}' at end of input

84: error: expected '}' at end of input

84: error: expected '}' at end of input

```
int isRegistered(FILE* fp, const char str[], char area[], char publisher[], char title[])
{
int areaa = 0;
int publc = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

  if(isValid(str))
  {
     if(fp)
     {
        for(; i < 5 && !areaa; i)
        {
           area[i] = str[i];
           area[i + 1] = '\0';
           if (isRegistered(fp, atoi(area)))
              areaa = 1;
           else
              areaa = 0;
        }
           cout << minNoDigits(fp, atoi(area)) << endl;
              int k = i;
                 for(; i < k; minNoDigits(fp, atoi(area)) && !publc; i , j)
                 {
                    if (str[i] == '0')
                    {
                       publisher[j] = str[i];}
                       publisher[j + 1] = '\0';
                    }
                       cout << publisher[j] <<endl;
                       && strlen(publisher) == minNoDigits(fp, atoi(area))
                          if(isRegistered(fp, atoi(area), publisher) && strlen(publisher) >= minNoDigits(fp, atoi(area)))
                               publc = 1;
                            else
                               publc = 0;
                 }
                    for(j = 0; i < 9; i, j)
                    {
                       title[j] = str[i];
                       title[j + 1] = '\0';
                    }
       }
    }
    return publc;
}
```

Comment: Why not sort out the formating? Also tell us what line is 62.

Comment: I would recommend using an IDE or something like GEdit or Notepad++ that has bracket matching and basic syntax highlighting options to help avoid basic mistakes like these.

Comment: +1, the comment from Alex W sums up all three present (at the moment) answers. We should have "SO is not a syntax checker!" in meta.

Answer (score 8):

`publisher[j] = str[i];}` - remove closing bracket here

Answer (score 6):

This line does not look right at all

```
    for(; i < k; minNoDigits(fp, atoi(area)) && !publc; i , j)
```

Comment: none of the `for` loops looks right

Comment: @skyel, you mean other than the fact it has four terms instead of three? (The extra `i, j` at the end - note the opening paren is followed by `;`.)

Answer (score 4):

You have this line:

```
&& strlen(publisher) == minNoDigits(fp, atoi(area))
```

which looks unfinished.